# Grep for a range of numbers in parenthesis

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to grep for only for a range of numbers located inside parenthesis. My current grep will pull everything within the parenthesis but I just want anything from `[0001-9999]`. How can I fix my grep to do this?

I have tried a few different version of this `(?<=\()[0001-9999](?=\))` but they don't return anything

```
$ cat /tmp/output
This is R3trans version 6.26 (release 745 - 24.03.17 - 20:17:03).
R3trans finished (0000).
R3trans finished (0001).
R3trans finished (9999).
05.03.2018 16:30:02
enserver, EnqueueServer, RED, Running, 2018 02 27 09:15:52, 151:14:10, 19069
```

Current output

```
$ cat /tmp/output | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
release 745 - 24.03.17 - 20:17:03
0000
0001
9999
```

Desired output

```
$ cat /tmp/output | grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))'
0001
9999
```

Comment: You want only four digit numbers?  Why is `[0-9]{4}` not working?  Or, if your RE implementation does not support curly-brace counters, `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`?

Comment: That is close but I only want 0001 to 9999
`$ cat /tmp/output | grep -Po '(?<=\()[0-9]{4}(?=\))'
0000
0001
9999`

Comment: So take that and strip out `0000` with an inverse search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two approaches to reach the goal:

**`grep`** approach (with *Perl* support):

```
grep -Po '\(\K(?!0000)([0-9]{4})(?=\))' /tmp/output
```

---

GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk -v FPAT='\\([0-9]{4}\\)' '$1{ n = substr($1,2,4); if (int(n) > 0) print n }' /tmp/output
```

---

The output:

```
0001
9999
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{4}' /path/to/file | grep -v '0000'
```

Less readable, but with only one `grep`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{3}[1-9]|[0-9]{2}[1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]{3}' /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you have numeric constrains. If this is the case, why not using a programming language? Example:

```
perl -nE '/\((\d{4})\)/ and $1 > 0 and say $1'
```

Comment: (assuming there's only one occurrence per line)